# How do I fill up a list in this large piece of code?

Tags: ada

I wrote this Parser incorrectly. My professor says that I am using the tokens inappropriately. The problem is that I'm trying to access the tokens from an empty list. How can I possibly fill up the list with tokens in order to make sure that the program analyzes the tokens so the Eiffel code can execute. That is why I am getting this error:

```
raised SYSTEM.ASSERTIONS.ASSERT_FAILURE : failed precondition from lexical_analyzers.ads:20
```

The code can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZPyNRv7C3hV3NRUVBnN0prbEE/view?usp=sharing

The error comes from the lexical_analyzers.ads and the parsers.adb classes.

Comment: Your questions aren’t really appropriate for the broader SO (from the help, ‘Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.’), and might well be regarded as candidates for being closed. SO wants questions and their answers to be a resource for the future: you’re quite likely to remove the Google Drive archives soon, and then what use will this question and its answers be to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure `Parse` begins

```
procedure parse(p: in out Parser; f: out feature) is
   tok: Token;
   lex: Lexical_Analyzer;
   var: Id;
   com: Compound;
begin
```

so when you say

```
   get_next_token(lex, tok);
```

which `lex` is it using? Answer: the empty one that you created in the declarations. You should be using `p.lex`.

And in the next line but one, your call to `get_id` doesn’t pass `p`:

```
   var := get_id(tok);
```

and `get_id` repeats the pattern,

```
function get_id(tok: in Token) return Id is

   par: Parser;
   lex: Lexical_Analyzer;
   tok1: Token := tok;
   str: String := String(Tokens.get_lexeme(tok1));
begin
   get_next_token(lex, tok1);
```

In this case, you’ve done it twice; you’ve created a local `Parser` and `Lexical_Analyser` instead of passing in the `Parser` (and its contained `Lexical_Analyser`).

This is a pattern you seem to have repeated in several places in the code.

Comment: I edited my code adding in the p.lex stuff like you specified, and unfortunately, it didn't make a difference. I need to define something somewhere with the p.lex method. create_lexical_analyzer only works with a filename, and I don't have that in my classes. Here's my edited code. Changes can be seen in the parsers.adb class: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZPyNRv7C3hS3loV3pDX0YtSzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In case you didn’t notice, I updated the answer (last 2 paras).